# Why 'after' hook is not called when exception occur?

Tags: perl, event-handling, dancer

I create `Dancer` appliation and subscribe to hook [`after`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#after1)

> This hook runs after a request has been processed, but before the response is sent.

If I understand correct, even if exception occur the response is being processed, so this hook `after` should be called before error response is sent

Also I see [`after_error_render`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#after_error_render) hook. But it has so small documentation that I do not understand. Should it called additionally to `after` event when exception occur, or should it called instead of `after` event?

```perl
use Dancer;
 
get '/error' => sub {
    die "Error";
};

hook after => sub {
    warn "After render";
};


hook after_error_render => sub {
    warn "Error occur";
};

 
dance;
```

Comment: *"Why 'after' hook is not called when exception occur?"* Please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve] for more information

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Done

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems your question would be answered by simply running the program.

Comment: @ikegami: doc for [after](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#after1) `This hook runs after a request has been processed, but before the response is sent.` My request was processed, error message was rendered, so I expect `after` hook is called. But it was not. Thus I expect it was named as `after_success_render`. Like jQuery do for its `success/error/complete`